# Vmware local users

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I was trying to add local users to my esxi 5.5 cluster but there is no user and group option available, is windows authentication the only  way to add users and groups.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1027647

My environment - there is no listing for users and groups.

[image]

Comment: I tried this today and I do see the Local Users & Groups tab. Can you please show us a screenshot?

Comment: Do you have Active Directory?

Comment: You are checking the permission tab right...? The guide is only applicable to individual hosts... not for vCenter Server.

Comment: Local users for an esxi host can be added if you log in directly to an esxi host. In your case you have been loged in to vcenter. In vcenter if you want to add locally users you add them in Windows like I already replied...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Create local accounts for VMware ESXi via PowerCLI](https://www.geekandi.com/2013/08/16/create-local-accounts-for-vmware-esxi-via-powercli/) is older than 5.5 but maybe it still works.

Did you connect directly to your ESXi host or are you looking for the Local Users & Groups tab when connecting to vCenter? You won't find it there, you have to connect directly to the host.

*edit:* Your screenshot shows you're connected to vCenter, not directly to the ESXi host. The KB article clearly states that you have to

> log in to the host using the vSphere Client

and not the vCenter.

*edit2:*

I'm afraid we're talking at cross-purposes here. So let's start again!

1) The KB article you mentioned is about creating *ESX(i) local accounts* which you can use to log in *directly* to the ESX(i) host. You cannot use these accounts to grant access when connecting to vCenter. vCenter doesn't know about these accounts as they are local to the hosts. And, yes, you will have to create these accounts on all ESX(i) hosts; remember: They're *local to the hosts*. However, I don't think your users connect to the hosts directly. In that case http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1027647 won't help you.

2) If you're running vCenter on Windows you can create accounts in the Windows OS and grant them access in vCenter. To the best of my knowledge this is the only option if your vCenter version is < 5.0.

3) I don't know what vCenter version you're running. You said something about a 5.5 cluster; since you're screenshot shows that your host is running ESXi 4.1.0 you maybe run vCenter 5.5...? In that case, you can [add vCenter Single Sign-On Users](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-72BFF98C-C530-4C50-BF31-B5779D2A4BBB.html) and grant them access.

Comment: OK I'm looking to grant access to a number of vm, if I add users this way and loose the host and the vm vmotions to another, do I lose the permission, or do I have to setup the user x8 (for each host)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using VCenter on Windows. Then yes, if you want to add users to be able to access the cluster information and not only the individual esxi hosts. The only way to do that is to add them in Windows.